# Express $y= x^{3} - x^{2} - 5x - 3$ in its fully factorised form

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Don't know how to do this, please help. I have never done factorising cubic polynomials and don't know how to go about this

Comment: What do you know how to factor?

Comment: "cubic  polynomials"  would  look  better  here  than  "  $4$  term  polynomials"

Comment: I only know how to factorise trinomials

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the level of familiarity that your assignments are assuming, you may be able to get some traction by trying some values.  For instance, assuming you know the quadratic formula, you know that if you can find one factor by trial-and-error, you can use the quadratic formula to factor the remaining two (if they are real).

Furthermore, homework assignments often use integer roots.  You might expect, therefore, that some possible roots would be $+1$, $-1$, $+3$, or $-3$ (since $3$ is divisible by all of those).  Indeed, if you try (say) $x = 3$, you get $3^3-3^2-5\cdot3-3 = 27-9-15-3 = 0$.  Because $x^3-x^2-5x-3 = 0$ when $x = 3$, you know that $x-3$ must be a factor of $x^3-x^2-5x-3$.  Use polynomial division to obtain the quotient when dividing $x^3-x^2-5x-3$ by $x-3$ to obtain a second-degree polynomial (a quadratic expression, in other words).  If you know how to factor those, then you are home free.

Comment: That sounds very helpful, I'm just not sure how to do most of that stuff you mentioned above but thanks anyways

Comment: It's useful, when you ask questions on Math.StackExchange, to indicate which things you know how to do, and which things you don't, so that answers can be adjusted to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3-x^2-5x-3=x^3+2x^2-3x^2-6x+x-3$$
$$x^3+2x^2+x-3x^2-6x-3=0$$
$$x(x^2+2x+1)-3(x^2+2x+1)=0$$
$$(x^2+2x+1)(x-3)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to use the [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).

A polynomial $\mathrm{f}(x)$ is divisible by $(x-a)$ if $\mathrm{f}(a)=0$.

In your case, you have $\mathrm{f}(x) = x^3 - x^2 - 5x - 3$, and you need to find an $a$ for which
$$\mathrm{f}(a) = a^3 - a^2 - 5a - 3 =0 $$
This can often be done by trial-and-error, or by using the table function on a scientific calculator.

By checking whole number choices for $a$, with $-5 \le a \le 5$, we see that $a=-1$ work.

Since $\mathrm{f}(-1) = 0$, the Factor Theorem tells us that $(x-(-1)) = (x+1)$ divides $\mathrm{f}(x)$. Hence:

$$x^3 - x^2 - 5x - 3 \equiv (x+1)(x^2+px+q)$$
where $p$ and $q$ are numbers that you need to find. You can do one of two things:

1. Expand the right-hand side and then compare coefficients,
2. Use [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

If we expand, we see that $(x+1)(x^2+px+q) \equiv x^3+(p+1)x^2+(p+q)x+q$.
Comparing coefficients gives $p+1=-1$, $p+q=-5$ and $q=-3$. Clearly $p=-2$ and $q=-3$. Hence
$$x^3 - x^2 - 5x - 3 \equiv (x+1)(x^2-2x-3)$$
Now we need only factorise the quadratic $x^2-2x-3$, which gives $(x-3)(x+1)$. Hence 
$$x^3 - x^2 - 5x - 3 \equiv (x+1)(x+1)(x-3)$$